# Does Git merge to master delete unchanged files?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a two branch first one "master" second one "newFeature"

In the master branch, I add some file and change some functions it does not exist in `newFeature` branch and the same in `newFeature` have added some new files/code AND Change file it exists in two branches and I want to apply when merged

Now when I want to merge `newFeature` to master,

Should I lose something in the master or other branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git's merge operation considers exactly three points when doing a merge: the two heads (usually branches) that you want to merge, and the *merge base*, which is usually the point at which one was forked from the other.

When a merge occurs, Git considers the changes computed between each head and the merge base.  It then produces a result exactly like the merge base, but with both sets of changes added.  In other words:

- If you made a change on one side and not the other, Git will include the change.  A change in this case includes the addition, removal, or modification of a file or part of it.
- If you made a change to the same location on both sides, Git will produce a conflict.
- If you made no changes to a file or part of it, Git will include those portions unchanged.

So in your case, you've only added and modified things, so the merge result will include only additions and modifications, not removals.  It is possible you'll see a conflict, though.

Comment: Great, in conflict what should i do?

Comment: If you have a conflict, you should edit the conflicted file to look the way you want, save, and run `git add` on the conflicted files, and then run `git commit`.

Comment: Well, I will figure out when finishing the changes "D  Thank you ;)